# Negation, and supremum proof

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ be non-empty and bounded from above. Let $\epsilon>0$ show that

$\exists a \in A:A>sup(A)- \epsilon$

My hint is to form a negation of the statement so it should be: ?

$\neg \exists a \in A:A \leq sup(A)- \epsilon$

My attempt:

Let $a \in A$. Since $A$ is bounded from above $\exists$ a number $b \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $a \leq b$. But I am not really sure on how I should use the property of supremum in this case.. any hints is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant $\exists a\in A[a>\sup A-\epsilon]$.

The negation is not $\neg\exists a\in A[a\leq\sup A-\epsilon]$ but $\neg\exists a\in A[a>\sup A-\epsilon]$.

Further this is equivalent with $\forall a\in A[a\leq\sup A-\epsilon]$.

That actually tells us that $\sup A-\epsilon$ is an upper bound of $A$.

However we have $\sup A-\epsilon<\sup A$ so this contradicts that $\sup A$ is the **least** upper bound of $A$.

Our conclusion is that the negation of the statement is not true, hence the statement is true.

Comment: so it contradicts the first property of least upper bound?

Comment: what do you mean with "first property of least upper bound"? Characteristic for the least upper bound of $A$ is that all elements smaller that it are no upper bounds of $A$. This purely on base of definition of least upper bound.

Comment: thanks I will keep this in mind